# What are the marks on Index-tan's left eye?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

In the [Toaru Majutsu no Index specials](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5955/Toaru_Majutsu_no_Index_Specials), Index-tan is shown to have some marks on her left eye. However, she did not have any on the 'main anime'.

[image]

What is the significance of these marks?
If it was not explained anywhere, are there any speculations as to what it might mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, but when you say "anime specials", what are you referring to?  An OVA?

Comment: I've included a link to the MAL page of the specials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [some](https://twitter.com/kakuretajigen/status/15725106697342976) [attendees](http://yaplog.jp/sanka_kiroku/archive/385) at an
[Index II x Oreimo talk session in December 2010](http://www.project-index.net/tv/news/hp0001/index00320000.html), someone from the Index
staff said there that it was intended to look like [Kenji Ohtsuki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenji_Ohtsuki)'s face
paint.

[image: Kinniku Shōjo Tai]

It is simply the result of a play on words without any significance:

- In Japan, とある魔術の**禁書**目録 (*Toaru Majutsu no Index*) is
  often referred to as **禁書** (***kinsho***) in short.
- Ohtsuki is the vocalist/lyricist for the Japanese band
  **筋**肉**少**女帯 ([*Kinniku Shōjo Tai*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinniku_Sh%C5%8Djo_Tai)),
  which is often shortened as **筋少** (***kinshō***).